# Returning a multidimensional array from C to Lua

Tags: c++, lua

My question is admittedly similar to this:
[How to create nested Lua tables using the C API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630169/how-to-create-nested-lua-tables-using-the-c-api)

I thought that I understood that answer but I continue to have issues.

I have an array of objects that I'm trying to return.

```
        const char * pushlist[] = {
              "status", "cmdsequence", "timestamp", "gain",
        };
        int nItems = sizeof(pushlist) / sizeof(char *);
        int iDepth = -(1 + nItems);

        // //
        // What we want to do is essentially push an array of tables.
        // The tables have keys (see pushlist above) and values.
        // The array is indexed by integers from 1 through N.
        //
        lua_newtable( L );
        for( Json::Value::UInt i = 0; i != totFrames; i++ )
        {
            lua_pushnumber( L, i + 1 );  // push the array index
            lua_newtable( L );

            Json::Value frame = params["frameinfo"][i];

            // now push the table which will be at array index (i + 1)
            for( int n = 0; n < nItems; n++ )
            {
                lua_pushstring( L, pushlist[n] );                 // push key
                lua_pushnumber( L, frame[pushlist[n]].asUInt() ); // push value
            }
            lua_settable(L, iDepth);
            lua_settable(L, -3);    // (note 1) error here
        }
        lua_settable(L, iDepth);    // (note 2) not clear on the need for this
        lua_settable(L, -3);
        lua_setglobal( L, "framedata" );
```

So in Lua I want to see:

 [0] = {["status"] = 1, ["cmdsequence"] = 2, ["timestamp"] = 3, ["gain"] = 4}

...

[totFrames-1] = {["status"] = 5, ["cmdsequence"] = 6, ["timestamp"] = 7, ["gain"] = 8}

I'm not clear on what the 2 lua_settable's are for at note 2, but the answer I linked to above indicates they're needed.

The lua_settable(L, -3) (note 1) errors out.  I'm doing this in C++ and so I have that code bracketed in a try/catch.  When it hits that settable the first time it bails and goes to my catch.  I'm thinking I've corrupted the stack somehow but I don't see it.

---

Thanks @Omri Barel for the excellent answer.  I'm still not clear on what to do after the inner 'for' loop.

I now have this:
            const char * pushlist[] = {
                  "status", "cmdsequence", "timestamp", "gain",
            };
            int nItems = sizeof(pushlist) / sizeof(char *);

```
        // //
        // What we want to do is essentially push an array of tables.
        // The tables have keys (see pushlist above) and values.
        // The array is indexed by integers from 1 through N.
        //
        lua_newtable( L );
        for( Json::Value::UInt i = 0; i != totFrames; i++ )
        {
            lua_pushnumber( L, i + 1 );  // push the array index
            lua_newtable( L );

            Json::Value frame = params["frameinfo"][i];

            // now push the table which will be at array index (i + 1)
            for( int n = 0; n < nItems; n++ )
            {
                lua_pushnumber( L, frame[pushlist[n]].asDouble() ); // push value
                lua_setfield(L, -2, pushlist[n] );
            }
            lua_settable(L, -3);    // (note 1) error here
        }
        //lua_settable(L, -3);       <<-- not certain that this is required
        lua_setglobal( L, "framedata" );
```

I no longer blow up, but my Lua fails (no error message, it simply exits).  I suspect that I haven't corrupted the stack, but somehow I haven't completed this table properly and so my return is confused.

I push several other return values into the Lua stack before this array, and then one more after it.

My Lua call is like this:

```
       param1,param2,framedata,Err = CCall.ReadFromC( arg, arg );
```

---

I finally have this working.  It needs further testing, but seems correct so far.  Thanks again to @Omri Barel.  Here's the code snippet that I've ended up with.

```
        const char * pushlist[] = {
              "status", "cmdsequence", "timestamp", "gain",
        };
        int nItems = sizeof(pushlist) / sizeof(char *);

        // //
        // What we want to do is essentially push an array of tables.
        // The tables have keys (see pushlist above) and values.
        // The array is indexed by integers from 1 through N.
        //
        lua_newtable( L );
        for( Json::Value::UInt i = 0; i != totFrames; i++ )
        {
            Json::Value frame = params["frameinfo"][i];

            // now push the table which will be at array index (i + 1)
            lua_newtable( L );
            for( int n = 0; n < nItems; n++ )
            {
                const char * itemName = pushlist[n];
                if( frame[itemName].isNull() ) continue;
                lua_pushnumber( L, frame[pushlist[n]].asDouble() ); // push value
                lua_setfield(L, -2, pushlist[n] );
            }
            lua_rawseti(L, -2, i + 1);
        }
```

Comment: When setting `x[i]=y` with `i` being number, I suggest you use `lua_rawseti` instead of `lua_pushnumber` followed by `lua_settable`.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are pushing too many key/value pairs before you add them to the table. You should add one pair at a time.

When debugging Lua, the best thing you can do is dump the content of the stack very often, to check what's going on. There's some "stack dumping" code in "[Programming In Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.2.3.html)" (first edition is good enough for this).

Let's have a look at your code (inside the frame loop).

1. You create a table. The stack is:

   ... [table]
2. You push pairs of key / value:

   ... [table] [key] [value] [key] [value] [key] [value] [key] [value]
3. You call settable with `iDepth`, which doesn't look right to me. In this case `iDepth = -(1+nItems) = -5`. But you are pushing pairs, so it should be double that. But even if `iDepth` were right, you're still only calling it once, so it only removes a single pair from the stack:

   ... [table] [key] [value] [key] [value] [key] [value]
4. You call settable with -3, but -3 is [value] so you get an error.

You should call settable (with -3) after each key / value pair.

And I would also suggest using `setfield` which is a bit clearer. Instead of:

```
lua_pushstring(L, key);
lua_pushnumber(L, value);
lua_settable(L, -3);
```

You can use:

```
lua_pushnumber(L, value);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "key");
```

Comment: Thanks again @Omri Barel.  I have this working now and couldn't have done it without you.  I'll post my final code above.