# How to create table in table in Lua 5.1 using C-API?

Tags: lua-5.1, lua-c++-connection

I need to create construction like this in Lua **5.1** C-API, not in Lua 5.2 and above

```
a = {["b"] = {["c"] = {["d"] = {["e"] = "GOOD"}}}}

print(a.b.c.d.e);
```

Expected Result: GOOD

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create nested Lua tables using the C API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630169/how-to-create-nested-lua-tables-using-the-c-api)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Lua C API is stack based. That means that the behavior of most of the C API functions depends not only on the arguments given, but also on the contents of the Lua stack (which is part of the `lua_State*` variable commonly called `L`). What a particular API function expects in terms of stack contents and how it affects the elements of the stack, you'll have to look up in the [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#3.7).

Let's start with creating a table and assigning it to a global variable `a`:

```
lua_newtable( L );
lua_setglobal( L, "a" );
```

This is equivalent to the Lua code snippet: `a = {}`.

The documentation for [`lua_newtable()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_newtable) tells us that the function pushes the new table to the top of the Lua stack. That fits nicely with [`lua_setglobal()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_setglobal), which pops a value from the stack top and assigns it to the global variable of the given name. So both functions combined (as in the snippet above) are **balanced** in terms of stack effects. The nice thing about stack-balanced pieces of code is that you can insert them anywhere, and the combined code is still valid. (The general rule is: **You can replace a single statement with a series of statements, and vice versa, as long as the (combined) stack effects are the same**.) E.g.:

```
lua_newtable( L );  /* ==> stack: ..., {} */
lua_pushnil( L ); /* ==> stack: ..., {}, nil */
lua_pop( L, 1 ); /* ==> stack: ..., {} */
lua_setglobal( L, "a" ); /* ==> stack: ... */
```

will still assign a table to the global variable `a` because `lua_pushnil( L );` and `lua_pop( L, 1 );` combined don't change the Lua stack contents. Instead of this useless pushing/popping we will add code that modifies the table *after* it is pushed onto the stack, and *before* it is removed from the stack and assigned to the global variable. As I said, you can insert stack-balanced code pieces anywhere between two Lua C API functions, so you just have to identify the right spot where the stack contains all the elements you'll need.

We want to add a field to the table with the key `"b"` and another table as the value. The Lua C API function to do that is [`lua_settable()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_settable) (there are other convenience functions that work for certain key types only, e.g. [`lua_setfield()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_setfield), but we'll go with `lua_settable()` here). `lua_settable()` needs the table to store the key/value-pair in *somewhere* on the Lua stack (which usually means that you'll have to pass a stack index as an argument), and the key and the value as the two top-most elements on the stack. Both key and value (but not the table) will be popped by `lua_settable()`:

```
lua_newtable( L );  /* ==> stack: ..., {} */
lua_pushliteral( L, "b" ); /* ==> stack: ..., {}, "b" */
lua_newtable( L ); /* ==> stack: ..., {}, "b", {} */
lua_settable( L, -3 ); /* ==> stack: ..., {} */
lua_setglobal( L, "a" ); /* ==> stack: ... */
```

The equivalent Lua code would be `a = { b = {} }`

Often you don't really care about what is below a certain point of the Lua stack, and that's where indices relative to the stack top (the `-3` in the code snippet above) come into play. The `-3` refers to the table that is just below the key `"b"` (which is at `-2`) and below the other table (which is at the stack top at `-1`).

You'll probably already see where this is going: Now we want to modify the new table, so we add stack-balanced code at the right place (after the new table is pushed onto the stack). I'll skip a few steps and indicate where I've inserted code by indentation:

```
lua_newtable( L );  /* ==> stack: ..., {} */
{
  lua_pushliteral( L, "b" ); /* ==> stack: ..., {}, "b" */
  lua_newtable( L ); /* ==> stack: ..., {}, "b", {} */
  {
    lua_pushliteral( L, "c" ); /* == stack: ..., {}, "b", {}, "c" */
    lua_newtable( L ); /* ==> stack: ..., {}, "b", {}, "c", {} */
    {
      lua_pushliteral( L, "d" );
      lua_newtable( L );
      {
        lua_pushliteral( L, "e" );
        lua_pushliteral( L, "GOOD" );
        lua_settable( L, -3 );
      }
      lua_settable( L, -3 );
    }
    lua_settable( L, -3 ); */ ==> stack: ..., {}, "b", {} */
  }
  lua_settable( L, -3 ); /* ==> stack: ..., {} */
}
lua_setglobal( L, "a" ); /* ==> stack: ... */
```

When you are developing code with complex stack manipulations, it often helps to print out the current stack contents at key points, or at least check that the number of elements on the stack (see [`lua_gettop()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_gettop)) is what you expect. [Here](https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-moon#moon_stack_assert) is what I use for that.

Comment: Thanx for ansver. Maybe you know hot to add in the last table with name "d" not key "e" with value "GOOD", but another table existing table, not create new table?

Comment: `lua_newtable( L );` pushes a single value onto the Lua stack. You can replace that statement with a sequence of statements that in total pushes the same number of values onto the Lua stack. What those statements are depends on where your existing table is stored (there may be a `lua_getglobal()` involved).

Comment: Sure. In the third code snippet (the one that is equivalent to `a = { b = {} }`) replace the second `lua_newtable( L );` with `lua_getglobal( L, "myTable" );`. This would make it equivalent to `a = { b = myTable } }`. `lua_newtable()` and `lua_getgobal()` have the same stack effects, so the surrounding code can stay the same.