# How to create Lua table with name C-API

Tags: lua, lua-table, lua-api, lua-c++-connection

How to create Lua table from C-API like this:

```
TableName = {a, b, c}
```

How to set table name? I only know how to create table and put values, but don't know how to set name of table.

Code for creating table without name:

```
lua_createtable(L, 0, 3);

lua_pushnumber(L, 1);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "a");

lua_pushnumber(L, 2);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "b");

lua_pushnumber(L, 3);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "c");
```

Comment: For the sake for clarity, you are asking about a variable having the name TableName. A table, like any Lua value, does not have a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is to add this line at the end

```
lua_setglobal(L, "TableName");
```

However, your C code is not equivalent to your Lua code. The C code corresponds to this Lua code:

```
TableName = { a=1, b=2, c=3 }
```

If you want C code equivalent to

```
TableName = {"a", "b", "c"}
```

use

```
lua_pushliteral(L, "a"); lua_rawseti(L, -2, 1);
lua_pushliteral(L, "b"); lua_rawseti(L, -2, 2);
lua_pushliteral(L, "c"); lua_rawseti(L, -2, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks. And how I can set the table in the table in the table? Like this a = {["b"] = {["c"] = {["d"] = {["e"] = "GOOD"}}}} ? print(a.b.c.d.e);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854422/how-to-create-table-in-table-in-lua-5-1-using-c-api