# How to add an empty table to an existing table in Lua using its C-API?

Tags: lua, lua-table, lua-api

The core detail of my problem is: I don't know how to do it.

I encountered the problem I'm trying to solve by wanting to add a table to an existing table in Lua.

The major difficulty that prevented me from solving it myself is ignorance, and a failure to come across any internet search results that are useful to me in solving the problem, despite my best efforts.

I tried the following, among other things:

```
  lua_getglobal(L, "OuterTable"); 
    lua_createtable(L, 0,0); 
    lua_pushliteral(L, "InnerTable");
    lua_settable(L,-2);
```

I expected that "InnerTable" would be added to "OuterTable" after considering the accepted answer of this question:

[How to create table in table in Lua 5.1 using C-API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854422/how-to-create-table-in-table-in-lua-5-1-using-c-api)

Which also used `lua_settable` to add a table to a table, albeit a newly created one.

I have also looked through Programming In Lua, the [color table example](https://www.lua.org/pil/25.1.html), but I was not able to solve it with that one, either.

Minimum reproducible example:

test.lua

```
OuterTable = {
    ExampleInnerTable = {}
}
```

Testbed in C (I use Lua 5.3 but my distro is set up in a peculiar way so ...I don't know how YOU would include it, be wary of that)

```
  #include <lua5.3/lua.h>
  #include <lua5.3/lualib.h>
  #include <lua5.3/lauxlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    


  lua_State* L;
  L = luaL_newstate();
  luaL_openlibs(L);
  luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua");

 lua_getglobal(L, "OuterTable"); 
 int c = lua_gettop(L);
 lua_newtable(L);
 lua_pushliteral(L, "InnerTable");
 lua_settable(L,c);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I want to add another table to `OuterTable`, one like `ExampleInnerTable`

Desired result

```
OuterTable = {
    ExampleInnerTable = {}
   ,InnerTable = {}
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example, e.g. a C file I can feed my compiler which doesn't work if executed?

Comment: I have updated my question with that (and accidentally deleted the comment where I told you this already, while thinking that clicking "delete" on a new comment would cancel the creation of the comment. Thus...this duplicate. Sorry , lol.

Comment: You know, I think this actually works... I just failed to 're push' the initial global, outer table, onto the stack to inspect it ...since settable pops things off the thing. ...dang. I'm sorry for the confusion and inconvenience. Do I delete non questions like this? Or what happens to em?

Comment: Heh, the rubber ducky effect in action again :) Deletion should be fine. You could also answer it yourself if you believe your answer may be useful to others (but this doesn't seem to be the case). Otherwise it would probably be closed as "not reproducible or caused by a typo".

Comment: Yes, SO can be used as a rubber duck :-)